How to resolve unknown error thrown at useSelector : Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: useSyncExternalStore is not a function?
The full error is :
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: useSyncExternalStore is not a function. (In 'useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSelection, getServerSelection)', 'useSyncExternalStore' is undefined)


This happens only when I add the following code :
  const mfeConfig = useSelector((state: any) => state.ccmConfig);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("calculator", mfeConfig)
  },[mfeConfig]);

Since I have added redux-saga and have got it to work, I assumed my react-redux package was good too, but the issue only happens when I useSelector so maybe I think this is an issue with my react dependencies but I don't know what the issue is:
npm uninstall react-redux
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-redux@9.1.2
npm ERR! Found: @types/react@17.0.75
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/base@5.0.0-beta.37
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/base
npm ERR!     @mui/base@"5.0.0-beta.37" from @mui/material@5.15.11
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.15.11
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.15.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!     @mui/icons-material@"^5.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   14 more (@mui/material, @mui/private-theming, @mui/system, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^18.2.25" from react-redux@9.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!   peerOptional react-redux@"^7.2.1 || ^8.1.3 || ^9.0.0" from @reduxjs/toolkit@2.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit
npm ERR!     @reduxjs/toolkit@"^2.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@18.3.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^18.2.25" from react-redux@9.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!     peerOptional react-redux@"^7.2.1 || ^8.1.3 || ^9.0.0" from @reduxjs/toolkit@2.2.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit
npm ERR!       @reduxjs/toolkit@"^2.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 

Im using the following packages :
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-select": "^5.7.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "recharts": "^2.8.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.13",


The issue was in fact with issue version 9 of react-redux, removing package and using 8.1.3 fixed issue and need for legacy-peer-deps npm flag.
